# Javascript script.js 404 error only sometimes

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

Working on my project, the JS script file only loads around half the time which is very frustrating. The error I receive is

`localhost/:252          GET http://localhost/js/script.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

I require the file at the bottom of the footer, which is in a blade component used on every page:

```
<x-footer />
```

```
</body>
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}"></script>
</html>`
```

I have tried moving the script file, renaming it, having it hard coded into each page instead of a blade component and still nothing works

Permissions of my public folder:

```
    total 32
0 drwxr-xr-x  11 brandon  staff   352  4 Nov 14:35 .
0 drwxr-xr-x  30 brandon  staff   960  4 Nov 14:33 ..
8 -rw-r--r--   1 brandon  staff   603 28 Oct 14:38 .htaccess
0 drwxr-xr-x   4 brandon  staff   128  4 Nov 14:33 build
0 drwxr-xr-x   3 brandon  staff    96  3 Nov 15:55 css
0 -rw-r--r--   1 brandon  staff     0 28 Oct 14:38 favicon.ico
8 -rw-r--r--   1 brandon  staff    21 11 Nov 15:57 hot
0 drwxr-xr-x   6 brandon  staff   192  3 Nov 16:08 img
8 -rw-r--r--   1 brandon  staff  1710 28 Oct 14:38 index.php
0 drwxr-xr-x   3 brandon  staff    96 11 Nov 15:53 js
8 -rw-r--r--   1 brandon  staff    24 28 Oct 14:38 robots.txt
```

and the JS file

```
 0 drwxr-xr-x   3 brandon  staff     96 11 Nov 15:53 .
 0 drwxr-xr-x  11 brandon  staff    352  4 Nov 14:35 ..
24 -rw-r--r--   1 brandon  staff  11937 14 Nov 11:54 script.js
```

**FIXED! It appeared to be a docker issue. I had to docker compose down and docker compose up the container, which fixed it.**

Comment: Are you using CLI?

Comment: check permissions of the file script.js

Comment: How does that look?

Comment: @bfrith you need to post the output when you are inside the `js` folder too.

Comment: All done, sorry!

Comment: Can you execute `chmod 755 scripts.js` while in the `js` folder and check if that works?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have had any effect unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

FIXED! It appeared to be a docker issue. I had to run `docker compose down` and `docker compose up` the container, which fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Move your JS files into the `/public` folder in your project, as the `asset(...)` method uses the path from the public folder.

So your JS files should be in `/public/js/script.js`

Comment: It is already in public/js/script.js

Comment: @bfrith alright, what are the permission of the file in the `js` folder?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check this haha, could you let me know how please?

Comment: Go to the public folder using the command line and enter `ls -lsa` and post the results as an edit in your question.

Comment: All done! How's that look?